# fseek on EOF character

Tags: c, eof, fseek

I'm currently using `fgetc()` in loop for reading whole file.

But I need to detect `EOF` in two iterations of this loop.
I know that `EOF` can't be returned to stream using `ungetc()`.

What about using

```
fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR)
```

Is it safe and portable to get before `EOF` using `fseek` and read it again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)
```

If you try to read from it, you'll get your second EOF.

**EDIT:**

Reading the reference more carefully: **"Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support SEEK_END (therefore, code using it has no real standard portability)."**

I guess your solution is the best one in terms of portability.

Just be careful with fseek (as a note because this is not your case I believe): [Using fseek to backtrack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780303/using-fseek-to-backtrack?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

On most operating systems, `EOF` is not a physical character that is present in the file. It's simply a virtual "out of band" character that `fgetc()` is returning to signal that there is no more input.

Why would you ever need to get the `EOF` again? There is no more data in the file, so what's the point of "backing up" to hit end of file again?

Comment: This loop is inside function (lexical analysis) and I need that loop to detect it independently from previous characters as next token.